# Spark throwing Out of Memory error

Tags: scala, memory-management, cassandra, apache-spark

I have a single test node with 8 GB ram on which I am loading barely 10 MB of data(from csv files) into Cassandra(on the same node itself). Im trying to process this data using spark(running on the same node).

Please note that for SPARK_MEM, Im allocating 1 GB of RAM and SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY I'm allocating the same. The allocation of any extra amount of memory results in spark throwing a "Check if all workers are registered and have sufficient memory error", which is more often than not indicative of Spark trying to look for extra memory(as per SPARK_MEM and SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY properties) and coming up short.

When I try to load and process all data in the Cassandra table using spark context object, I'm getting an error during processing. So, I'm trying to use a looping mechanism to read chunks of data at a time from one table, process them and put them in another table.

My source code has the following structure

```
var data=sc.cassandraTable("keyspacename","tablename").where("value=?",1)
data.map(x=>tranformFunction(x)).saveToCassandra("keyspacename","tablename")

for(i<-2 to 50000){
    data=sc.cassandraTable("keyspacename","tablename").where("value=?",i)
    data.map(x=>tranformFunction(x)).saveToCassandra("keyspacename","tablename")    
}
```

Now, this works for a while, for around 200 loops, and then this throws an error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create a new native thread.

I've got two questions:

```
Is this the right way to deal with data?
How can processing just 10 MB of data do this to a cluster?
```

Comment: It's out of topic, but even [42 killobytes of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) can bring your cluster down. (in other words, do not assume that 10 MB on disk == 10 MB in memory, depending on your usage pattern, that data may grow insanely)

Comment: 1 UP for clearing that up.. :-), and I've mentioned my basic usage pattern(for now) as code. Just taking, transforming and storing back(with just 1 intermediate variable in between).

Comment: Could you show the code you first tried, before trying the looping mechanism you show above? Also can you summarize what transformFunction() is doing to the data?

Answer (score 1):

You are running a query inside the for loop. If the 'value' column is not a key/indexed column, Spark will load the table into memory and then filter on the value. This will certainly cause an OOM.

Comment: But for me, the 'value' column is indexed. But regardless of whether or not it is indexed, internally, doesnt the query go like: select <columns> from <table> where token(<keyColumn>) > 0 and value=? allow filtering. So, I'm doubtful whether spark will first load the entire table and then perform filtering. But, I might be wrong.